# Why am I unable to npm install npm react-google-charts

Tags: reactjs, npm, google-visualization

In and existing react project and after creating a fresh project with `npm init` after I try to run `npm install react-google-charts` Why do I get the following error (edited some lines away)?

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "react-google-charts"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
...
npm ERR!     /home/joel/tmp/nodetest/npm-debug.log
```

I am trying to get version 1.6, but even without version it fails. With `npm search react-google-charts` I see it does exist:

```
react-google-charts React component    =rakannimer       2018-08-21 3.0.6
```

Comment: Hmmm npm version seems a bit old for the corresponding node version. Could you do an update (e.g. `npm install -g npm` might do, but might block at the same error and require manual installation of npm latest). If I am not mistaken and npm is indeed old for your node version, you could also investigate why (e.g. problematic PATH or other env?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update NPM on your machine. That should fix this error.

Comment: I have no idea why I asked this question anymore or what I did to it. I think I even reinstalled linux after this, but I'll accept this answer as it seems good.

Answer (score 0):

I use ubuntu 18.04 and I can not update lastest version of npm but luckily, I clone it from github and then it works. May this help you.